# Unable to load config data from 'aws-parameterstore:' when using Spring Boot with AWS Parameter store

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

Spring Boot newbie here. I am trying to read credentials from AWS Parameter Store. To do that, I have added the following dependencies to `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using Spring Boot version version `2.7.4`. When I run the application, it fails to boot and prints the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'aws-parameterstore:'
```

How do I read credentials from AWS parameter store?

### Update

There is a parameter stored at the path `/config/myap_dev/dummy`. I have added the following config to my `bootstrap.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=myapp
aws.paramstore.defaultContext=application
aws.paramstore.profileSeparator=_
aws.paramstore.prefix=/config
aws.paramstore.enabled=true
```

and in my `application-dev.yaml` I do the following to retrieve the parameter:

```
spring.config.import: "aws-parameterstore:"
param: "${dummy}"
```

I am running the application using `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: This doesn't show how your are fetching the aws-parameterstore? How do you run it? etc...

Comment: @grekier I updated my question to include more details. Please let me know if I should add something more.

Comment: How do you have access to AWS defined? Do you have env variable for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_REGION, and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY or something else? I also think you need to set `AWS_EC2_METADATA_DISABLED=true` and `cloud.aws.stack.auto=false` when not running in AWS

Comment: @grekier It's running locally with `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_REGION`, and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` defined as environment variables. I added `cloud.aws.stack.auto: false` but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in AWS then ensure that the service you're using (e.g. an ECS task) has permission to access the parameter store.  See section 3.3 here https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/current/reference/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect dependency in your pom:

`spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config`

...should be...

`spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config`

Hope it helps, took quite a lot to figure out and probably package names could be confusing.